# Bits Shift in C- is the i bit on?

Tags: c, bit-shift

I'm trying to understand the following function which decides whether a bit is on:

```
int isBitISet( char ch, int i )
{
   char mask = 1 << i ;
   return mask & ch ;
}
```

First, why do I get a char? for `ch=abcdefgh` and `i=5` the function suppose to return the fifth bit from the right (?) , `d`. so  `mask=00000001<<5=00100000`, and `00100000 & abcdefgh = 00c00000`.

Can you please explain me how come we get char and we can do all these shifts without any casting? how come we didn't get the fifth bit and why the returned value is really the Indication whether the bit is on or not?

Edit: the 'abcdefg' are just a symbols for the bits, I didn't mean to represent a string in a char type.

I used to think of a char as `'a'` and not as an actual 8 bits, so probably this is the answer to my first question.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding something... In C a `char` is 8 bits, and can only have a value between 0 and 255 (for unsigned) or -128 to 127 (for signed). A `char` can never have a value such as `abcdefgh`. Maybe you are thinking about `char *` and strings? In that case you can't use bitmasks.

Comment: the 'abcdefg' are just a symbol for the bits, I didn't mean to send string in a char type.

Comment: `h` is considered as 0th bit here and c is the fifth bit. Code is absolutely fine.

Comment: each char in "abcdefgh" represents a bit???? Shall i take in that point of view??? Because 8 chars you used.

Comment: Ah, you mean that `abcdefgh` is just an arbitrary bitpattern? In that case you might want to read up a bit more on how the bitwise operators work (i.e. bitwise and, or and xor).

Comment: O.k, I got it all, Thanks for all the answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't give you the fifth bit. Binary numbers start at 2<sup>0</sup>, so the first bit is actually indexed with `0`, not with `1`. It will give return you sixth bit instead.

Examples:

```
ch & (1 << 0); // first bit
ch & (1 << 1); // second bit
ch & ((1 << 3) | (1 << 2)); // third and fourth bit.
```

Also, a char is only an interpretation of a number. On most machines it has a size of 8 bit, which you can either interpret as a unsigned value (0 to 255) or signed value (-128 to 127). So basically it's an integer with a very limited range, thus you can apply bit shifting without casting.

Also, your function will return an integer value that equals zero if and only if the given bit isn't set. Otherwise it's a non-zero value.

Answer (score 1):

The function may return a char, because the input it works on is also a char only. You certainly can not pass in ch=abcdefgh, because that would be a string of 8 chars.

Comment: the 'abcdefg' are just a symbol for the bits, I didn't mean to send string in a char type

Answer (score 1):

You can do shifts on chars, because C allows to do it. `char` is just an 8-bit integer type so there's no need to disallow it.

You are right about the fact, that `isBitISet(abcdefgh, 5)` returns `00c00000` if the letters a, b, etc. are bits in the binary representation of numbers.
The return value is not `the fifth bit from the right`, it is the same number as in the input, but with all the bits but the fifth bit zeroed.
You also have to remember that numbering of bits goes from zero, so the fifth bit being `c` is correct, just as that the zeroth bit is `h`.

This example uses an integer type to represent a boolean value. This is common in C code prior to C99, as C didn't have the `bool` type.
If you treat your return value as a boolean value, remember that everything non-zero is true, and zero is false. Hence, the output of `isBitISet` is true for C if bit `i` is set, and false otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You should know by now that in computers, everything starts with 0. That is, bit number 5 is in fact the sixth bit (not the fifth).

Your analysis is actually correct, if you give it `abcdefgh` and `5`, you get `00c00000`.

When you do the "and":

```
return mask & ch;
```

since `mask` has type `int`, `ch` will also automatically be cast to `int` (same way as many other operators). That's why you don't need explicit casting.

Finally, the result of this function is in the form 0..0z0..0. If `z`, the bit you are checking for is 0, this value is 0 which is false as long as an `if` is concerned. If it is not zero, then it is true for an `if`.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, this function does not return the i-th bit, but tells you if that bit is on or off.
2. The usage of `char mask` is implementation depend here. Simply defines an 8-bit mask since the value on which to apply this mask is a `char`.
3. Why would you need a cast when `1` is a char? `i` is only an value for << operator.
4. `ch=abcdefgh` makes no sense as an input. `ch` is char, so `ch` can only be one character.
5. The working is as follows: first you construct a mask to zero all the bits you don't need. So for example if the input is `ch = 204` (`ch = 11001100`) and we want to know if the 6th bit is on, so i = 5. So `mask = 1 << 5 = 00100000`. Then this mask is applied to the value with an AND operation. This will zero everything except the bit in question: `11001100 & 00100000 = 00000000 = 0`. As 0 is false in C, then 6th bit is not set. Another example on same `ch` input and i = 6: `mask = 1 << 6 = 01000000`; `11001100 & 01000000 = 01000000 = 64`, which is not 0, and thus true, so 7th bit is set.

Comment: `1` is a `char`? And there are basically no operations in C that are done in `char`, all arguments of operators in C are promoted to `int` if they are narrower than that.

Comment: Well 1 is a char, why not? ASCII code 1. I don't see what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
return 0 != (mask & ch) ;
```

if you want a bool (0x00000000 or 0x00000001) return. `mask & ch` alone will give you the bit you're asking about at correct position.

(others said more than enuff about i=5 being sixth bit)

Comment: @m0skit0, C has the `_Bool` type and the macro `bool` that points to it since C99, this is for 13 years now. Wake up!